# Date format in JavaScript and Java

Tags: java, javascript

I have these time formats in Java which I use to format the date:

```
dd-mm-yyyy
dd-mm-rr
dd-mon-yyyy
dd-mon-rr
dd/mon/yyyy
```

When I use these time formats with JQuery time picker I get this output:

```
24-08-rr
24-08-20122012
```

Can you tell me how I can use one time format for Java and for JavaScript? How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Java is not Javascript. Except for the similar names, they're not related, and date formats in one are not going to be same as date formats in the other. You will have to adjust your format strings as necessary for each language.

Comment: [This post](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format) describes how to format dates in Javascript.

Comment: What is "rr" in your format string?

Comment: JQuery time picker  ? you mean http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ ? or any other plugin ?

Comment: If you can use momentjs on the client side, then you can use the [momentjs/SimpleDateFormat converter](https://github.com/MadMG/moment-jdateformatparser) to translate your SimpleDateFormat strings into momentjs format.

Answer (score 2):

For example you can use next:
-On client side

```
$("#input-field-id").datepicker().mask("99/99/9999");
```

-On server side

```
org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER =
      DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");  
DATE_TIME_FORMATTER.parseDateTime(dateThatYouGatFromClientPart);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use latest version of jQuery UI datepicker which has the following useful functions

- http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate
- http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/parseDate